# Как ввести дату?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

```
while True:
    book = knigi(book=str(input("Создайте книгу с названием \n"))
    name = str(input("Имя автора \n"))
    vypusk = datetime.date(input("Введите дату выпуска \n" year=a, month=b, day=c )))
```

У меня класс, где надо создать книгу и инициализировать ее, в остальном участке нет ошибок, я точно понимаю, что я не знаю, как вводить от консоли именно дату для инициализации...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из `input` вводится строка, ее парсите через `DT.datetime.strptime` и получаете дату:

```
import datetime as DT

date_str = input("Введите дату выпуска (dd/mm/yyyy)\n")
vypusk = DT.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
print(vypusk)
```

Результат:

```
Введите дату выпуска (dd/mm/yyyy)
10/02/2021
2021-02-10
```